Using a merge function using scala via Databricks is creating additional columns in target table which is causing failure due to schema mismatch
I have a problem with a task in work.  My Manager has asked that I create scala code that will upsert data from source table to a target table as well as delete from target table if the data row has been deleted in source, all within databricks.
From what I've read in the databricks documents, the merge function would achieve this. I should state that I am a novice at scala so there's probably other methods of dealing with this, but this is the way I've found to do it.
I can achieve this using the below SQL:
MERGE INTO  G
USING  B
ON G.list_id = B.list_id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET
    G.list = B.list,
    G.label = B.label,
    G.value = B.value,
    G.action = B.action,
    G.sort_order = B.sort_order,
    G.locale = B.locale,
    G.active = B.active,
    G.role_permissions = B.role_permissions
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (list_id, list, label, value, action, sort_order, locale, active, role_permissions)
  VALUES (B.list_id, B.list, B.label, B.value, B.action, B.sort_order, B.locale, B.active, B.role_permissions);

DELETE FROM G
WHERE list_id NOT IN (SELECT list_id FROM B);


However, because this code is part of a large scala script, I need to convert this into Scala which I've done in the below;
val bDF = spark.table("B")
val gDF = spark.table("G")
val deleteGoldDF = spark.sql(
"""
DELETE FROM G
WHERE list_id NOT IN (SELECT list_id FROM B)
"""
)
deleteGoldDF.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("G")
val mergedQueryDF = spark.sql(
"""
MERGE INTO  G
USING  B
ON G.list_id = B.list_id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET
G.list = B.list,
G.label = B.label,
G.value = B.value,
G.action = B.action,
G.sort_order = B.sort_order,
G.locale = B.locale,
G.active = B.active,
G.role_permissions = B.role_permissions
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (list_id, list, label, value, action, sort_order, locale, active, role_permissions)
VALUES (B.list_id, B.list, B.label, B.value, B.action, B.sort_order, B.locale, B.active, B.role_permissions)
"""
)
val filteredMergedDF = mergedQueryDF.select(
"list_id", "list", "label", "value", "action", "sort_order", "locale", "active", "role_permissions"
)
filteredMergedDF.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("G")

G= Target table
B= Source table
The overall aim of my code is that using the match criteria of list_id = list_id, the code should update the target table with the data in the source table, if the list_id exists in the source table and not the target table, insert all columns.  If a list_id exists in target table and not source, delete that list_id in target table.
However, when I run this, I'm getting error messages stating that the schemas are mismatched.  Both tables have the same schema, G is a copy of B. I've found that the mergeQuery is trying to add another column to the target table, which I don't want, both tables need to match. I've tried to workaround this by specificlly selecting the columns I want and writing to the target table but to no avial, I've also tried a similar approach but dropping the additional column but still getting the same issue.
Does anyone have any ideas on how to get this to work correctly or advise on another approach to this?
I've isolated the SQL portion and it runs as expected, it's just an issue when I introduce it to the scala code.
I've tried specifically selecting the columns I want and also dropping the column I don't want but still getting the schema mismatch error.

Hi - please update your question with the exact error message that's being generated. Also, which column is being added to the target?
